# Howto block all SSH connection attempts coming in from $extif

Tags: freebsd, pf

What is the PF notation to block on $ext_if all incoming SSH connection attempts?
$ext_if is the interface pointing toward the internet. Somthing like:

```
block quick in on $ext_if proto tcp to port 22
```

but that seems an invalid syntax

Comment: Would it not be easier to avoid listening on that interface though modifying the `sshd_config` file?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should  set ```ListenAddress``` to the addres off the internal interface. But besides that, still, I have problems understanding the "PF" syntax. How would the rules be spelled to block via PF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block or pass rules always need to come after NAT and redirections.

You have an `in` too much (or misplaced). It is simply `block on $ext_if`. And if you want to bypass further processing `block quick on $ext_if`. If only in one direction then `block in quick on $ext_if` (Notice: direction after action!)

So what you probably want is:

```
block in quick on $ext_if proto tcp to port ssh
```

The general, highly simplified syntax for filter rules is:

```
action [direction] [log] [quick] [on interface] [af] [proto protocol]
       [from src_addr [port src_port]] [to dst_addr [port dst_port]]
       [flags tcp_flags] [state]
```

You should check your ruleset using `pfctl -nf /etc/pf.conf`.